# Chaquopy does not work on Android studio emulator

Tags: python, android-studio, android-emulator, chaquopy

I'm trying to run a python file(a very simple one that prints "hello world") in Android Studio with chaquopy.
The file compiles fine, but when it starts launching on emulator, the device enters a blank window, **stays there for 1-2 seconds and quits it without printing out anything.**

I have no idea what to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: did you get any error in console.

Comment: Please check the [logcat window](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html), and edit your question to add any relevant messages.